# Different html body height for virtually same React code

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I tried to replicate the [react-resizable-panels](https://react-resizable-panels.vercel.app/examples/horizontal) example component usage by copying over the code to Codesandbox. But in the codesandbox, the content doesn't take up the whole viewport height. There's absolutely no difference in styles as far as I can tell. The `body` height is 100%. It seems to expand it to full-height only in the `react-resizable-panels` example.

Here are the two identical code examples for reference:

- Original extracted: https://react-resizable-panels.surge.sh
- Codesandbox clone: https://y6yhjv.csb.app

Any help with debugging the difference between the two examples would be highly appreciated.
Thanks. :)

Comment: Interesting, I'm suprised too why first example goes full height. The only difference that I can spot is first example is not in HTML5 standard since it is missing the <!DOCTYPE html> tag, Not sure is the issue related to [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the missing <!Doctype html> makes `react-resizable-panels` example revert back to 'quirks' mode and cause `html` and `body` take up 100% of the page height. Just tested with a quick code and below is the result.

See thoroughly for the structure in both and their respective computed height.

[image]

Comment: That indeed was the reason! I would have never thought of checking that!
Thanks Zeikman!

Comment: You're welcome. Myself also just realized about this too even I'm years in front-end. LOL. A learning for myself as well.

Comment: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-resizable-panels/issues/99

Logged the issue. Have a nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 1):

`height: 100%` requires a parent element to reference for height. I'm actually more surprised that the first example goes to full height.

Either way, adding `height: 100vh;` to your `<div id="root">` element (ie. parent element) will give you full height. Optionally, you could add it to the element that's currently set to `height: 100%`.

Comment: yes, that would indeed solve the issue and I am surprised by the first example as well
but this post of mine was more about understanding the difference between the two seemingly similar apps wrt css